# I am trying to filter directories out of a list using regex

Tags: python, regex

I have many directories and subdirectories in a list format and i am trying to pull out only the ones I need. I start with an array of xml files in the directory repo/bob/ebb. I would like to specifically locate the files in the following directories: where a dash means any character:

> repo/bob/ebb/bb--/nr/dl - - - - - - - - - - -/ [every xml inside this directory recursively]
>
> repo/bob/ebb/bb----/nr/dl - - - - - - - - - - -/ [every xml inside this directory recursively]

I have come up with the following code in order to do this but I am recieving a syntax error. I have started learing Regex yesterday and am probably not grasping something but this is my attempt. Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thank you in advance.

```
import glob
import re 
import os

x = glob.glob('/repo/bob/ebb/*/nr/*/*/*/*/test_suites.xml')
print x

for y in x:
    if re.search(r'/repo/bob/ebb/bb\+{2,4}/nr/dl\.+',y)
    print y
```

ps I realize I am using glob and can use the '+' but I would like to incorporate the regex into this.

I am getting "invalid syntax" at the search line so I am doing something wrong just unsure of what it is. thanks again

Comment: You need to start you regex with `r'...'`, I assume. But a full error traceback would help here.

Comment: Changed thank you for that still have the error

Comment: You need to show the entire traceback of the syntax error.  Just looking at the code you posted, the `if` statement is missing a closing colon, and the line below it isn't indented.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
"repo/bob/ebb/bb.{2,4}/nr/dl.+/.+\.xml"
```

The backslash (\) is an escape character in regular expressions. You have \+, which is essentially saying you want a literal '+' character. Instead, you want to use a '.' which matches any character. The {2,4} says it occurs anywhere from 2 to 4 times. Then at the end, you have a \.+ which should just be a .+ instead. Again, the backslash is escaping the period, so you are saying you want one or more periods. Instead, you want to say one or more 'any' characters.

A helpful site I've used countless times for testing regular expressions is https://www.regexpal.com. It allows you to dynamically play around with the regex and have a test string to visually see what matches and what doesn't.

Comment: thanks for the suggestion I tried and I am still getting a syntax error on the same line. thanks for resource.